# Can we use "sth that forms", "where sth collects", or "is deposited" for non-living items?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, sentence-structure

> [Source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mudflats&rlz=1C1HLDY_enIN693IN693&oq=mudflats&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>   Mudflats or mud flats, also known as tidal flats, are coastal wetlands **that form** when mud is deposited by tides or rivers.
>
> [Source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bayous&rlz=1C1HLDY_enIN693IN693&oq=bayous&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>   They are usually found in flat areas where **water collects** in pools.

I think that it should be **that are formed** and **water gets collected.** Is there personification used? Is it right to say,

> "Mudflats are coastal wetlands **that form** when **mud deposits** by tides or rivers"?

Comment: "Form" can be both transitive and intransitive verb.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, have you studied _transitive_ and _intransitive_ verbs?

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as answerable by a dictionary. I can see the confusion between "water collects in pools" and "water gets collected in pools" and think a good explanation would be helpful to other learners. The question could use some refinement, but I think it is OK to leave it open for answers in its current state.

Comment: Can anybody answer this?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh This answer by StoneyB should be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/54554/3281. Look for the "middle voice" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks goes to Damkerng T.'s comment for providing me direction:

The sentences given in the question are correct as they stand. This type of speech is called mediopassive voice.By Wikipedia,

> The mediopassive voice is a grammatical voice that subsumes the meanings of both the middle voice and the passive voice.

An excellent list of examples is taken as:

> The book reads well.
>
> The trousers wash easily.
>
> Ripe oranges peel well.
>
> The lost language from which all Indo-European languages derive.
>
> Hydrogen combines.

About 2nd part of the question, I am not sure if we can use it two times in a sentence.