# Has and is in a sentence

Tags: tense, grammaticality

Which sentence is correct?

1. Why ***has*** my order not shipped out?

or

2. Why ***is*** my order not shipped out?

Can someone tell me the grammatical rule on this? When do I use “has” and when do I use “is”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the difference between present passive voice and present perfect passive voice.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54550/the-difference-between-present-passive-voice-and-present-perfect-passive-voice) Where the texts being compared are ***The order has shipped*** and ***The order is shipped***.

Answer (score -1):

Neither one is really correct because you're asking whether *someone else* has done something with your order, which uses a passive construction.  The idiomatic way to ask is

> Why **has** my order not **been** shipped out?

This is because, in statement form, the company *has shipped* your order, so your order *has been shipped* by the company.

(To make things more confusing, people do sometimes say "The order shipped yesterday", using an active construction, but this is a rather slangy, informal usage.)

---

To answer your larger question about *is* vs. *has*:

We use **is** with adjectives, and with participles in the present continuous tense or passive constructions in the present.  Basically, use **is** if we're talking about something happening right now.

- My friend is afraid. / Is my friend afraid?
- My friend is running away. / Is my friend running away?
- Fruit is eaten by bears. / Is fruit eaten by bears?
- My friend is being eaten by a bear. / Is my friend being eaten by a bear?

We use **has** with participles in the present perfect.  Basically, use **has** if we're talking about something in the past that remains true.

- My friend has fallen down. / Has my friend fallen down?
- My friend has been eaten by a bear. / Has my friend been eaten by a bear?

(Note that these are not the only things you could use - you could also say "my friend had been eaten by a bear" or "my friend was eaten by a bear" - but you asked specifically about *is* vs. *has*.)

Comment: I disagree that we absolutely need “been” there.... “Your order has shipped.” “Why hasn’t my order shipped?” both seem valid and not informal or “slangy“ to me. An excerpt from a receipt from a large company: *If your order contains physical products, you will receive a separate email notification when your products **have shipped**.* not “have been shipped”.

Comment: (And that is not my downvote. I think the other parts of your answer are accurate)